# How to add an icon to marker without geojsonlayer in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: icons, mapbox-gl-js, marker

I have found following code:

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([-71.478, -53.628])
    .addTo(map);
```

It works great. Now I want to have a special icon or an image instead of the basic mapbox icon. How do I do this?
Mapbox gives many examples about giving icons and pictures to markers BUT I only found methods with geojson features (e.g. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/ ). But I dont want to create a geojson layer just because to load an icon. I just want to use these 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in that example that requires a GeoJSON layer.

You can just copy/paste this part of the example:

```
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
el.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://placekitten.com/g/30/30)`;
```

And then create the marker with that element:

```
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
...
```